# Run migrations on slave in typeorm

Tags: typeorm

I'm using replicas in the typeorm, and when running the migrations with the migrate:run command, only the master receives the changes. I would like to know if it is possible for me to run the migrations and reflect on the replica as well.
My config

```
{
  type: 'mysql',
  logging: true,
  replication: {
    master: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'secret@contents',
      database: 'ps-contents',
    },
    slaves: [{
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3307,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'secret@contents',
      database: 'ps-contents',
    }],
  },
  migrations: [join(__dirname, '..', 'database/migrations/*.{ts,js}')],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/infra/database/migrations',
  },
  entities: [join(__dirname, '..', 'database/entities/*.{ts,js}')],
  synchronize: true,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation doesn't say this directly, but it seems that you have to handle the replication mechanism yourself at the database level. TypeORM provides load-balancing mechanisms, allowing the use of slave-servers.

I infer it [from](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/multiple-connections#replication):

> All schema update and write operations are performed using master server. All simple queries performed by find methods or select query builder are using a random slave instance. [...]

I can be wrong, so follow the [issue report](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8702).